# Best way to go about solving specific tricky 2.ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been working on this equation for a while now. Find the particular solution of:

$$y''-4y'+y=te^t+t$$

My first instinct was to use the method of undetermined coefficients, solving for $te^t$ and $t$ separately.

So I tried this:$$y_{p1}=ate^t+be^t,  y_{p2}=at+b$$
I then worked out what these would be for $y''$ and $y'$ and put them back in the original equation $y''-4y+y$. This resulted in:$$y_{p1}:-2a-2at-2b=t,y_{p2}:a=t(1+3a)$$
So normally I'd be rid of the $t$'s and found a value for the $a$'s. Am I just doing this wrong, or can I not use undetermined coefficients here?

Anyways, I also tried variation of parameters and ended up with this abomination: $$y_h=c_1e^{2t+\sqrt{3}t}+c_2e^{2t-\sqrt{3}t}$$
Which gives: $$V_1'=-V_2'e^{2\sqrt{3}}$$
and $$V_2'(-e^{2\sqrt{3}t}+(2+\sqrt{3})e^{2t+\sqrt{3}t})=te^t+t$$

So how would you solve this task? Have I been doing it wrong?
Question has been answered:

**WORK:**

$$y_{p1}=ate^t+be^t,  y_{p2}=at+b$$ $$y_{p1}:-2a-2at-2b=t,y_{p2}:a=t(1+3a)$$

For $y_{p1}$:$$(-2a)t+(-2a-2b)=t$$$$-2at=t,-2a-2b=0$$$$a=-1/2,b=1/2$$

For $y_{p2}$:$$-4a+at+b=t$$$$at=t,-4a+b=0$$$$a=1,b=4$$

Making $$y_p=y_{p1}+y_{p2} = -1/2te^t+1/2e^t+t+4$$
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What made you think that the particular solution for the $\ldots = te^t$ portion would have the form $y = a t e^t$? It's been a long time since I did ODEs, but I'd have guessed $y = a t e^t + b e^t$ instead, esp. since *your* approach leads to $a = 0$, so that the particular solution is the zero-solution, which is not correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right, however I'm still not sure where to go from here: $$-2a-2at-2b=t$$

Comment: Polynomials $(-2a)t + (-2a - 2b)$ and $(1)t + (0)$ are equal if and only if coeffs are equal, i.e., $-2a = 1$ and $-2a - 2b = 0$. What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Right you are again! Guess I'll need another cup coffee. $$(-2a)t+(-2a-2b)=t$$$$-2at=t,-2a-2b=0$$$$a=-1/2,b=1/2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution for the homogeneous part of the ODE $y_h=c_1e^{2t+\sqrt{3}t}+c_2e^{2t-\sqrt{3}t}$ is OK.

In order to find a particular solution for the part of ODE : $y''-4y'+y=t$ it is also OK to presume the form $y_{p2}=at+b$. Put it into $y''-4y'+y=t$ and you will find $a=1$ and $b=4$.

In order to find a particular solution for the part of ODE : $y''-4y'+y=te^t$ you observe that $y_{p1}=2ate^t$ doesn't fit. Try  $y_{p1}=(At+B)e^t$. Put it into $y''-4y'+y=te^t$ and you will find $A=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$